# Django-admin can't run after fresh install

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ubuntu

(I'm new to SO also so I'm happy to change anything wrong with my post)

But I just installed Ubuntu LTS 16 and tried to get Django working.

I ran these commands, and then got the error below. Commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ pip3 install Django
$ sudo apt-get install python3-django
$ sudo django-admin startproject yourprojectnamehere
```

Error that I keep having, even after 2 OS reinstalls:

```
  File "/home/boo/.local/bin/django-admin", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/home/boo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps
  File "/home/boo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .config import AppConfig
  File "/home/boo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango41Warning
  File "/home/boo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 5, in <module>
    from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
  File "/home/boo/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 115
    launch_map: "Dict[asyncio.Task[object], threading.Thread]" = {}
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

anyone have any idea?

Is it not connecting to python3 or something?

My computer even says "System error, do you want to report?" and last time my whole Terminator terminal crashed and wouldn't restart so IDK if I'm messing up some system files or something too.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're running Python `3.5` but `asgiref` requires Python `3.6` or higher to run, according to [the official repo](https://github.com/django/asgiref).

To update your Python installation to a newer version, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1275294) may be helpful.

Comment: ok, if I'm updating my python, do I need to uninstall the Django I installed? and then reinstall it with the new python? or just update python and try using django again

Comment: According to the answer I shared, you probably will end up having two Python versions in parallel, `3.5` and `3.6` in your OS. I would expect having to reinstall a bunch of packages using python 3.6 (you can delete your project packages for Python `3.5`) but take this opportunity to use a virtual environment instead of installing every package in your system. Check out the `venv` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/venv.html).

Comment: Also, you can replace the default `python` and `pip` aliases to use the latest python version in your system otherwise you may end up using Python `3.5` by default when you execute `python`. check [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-multiple-alternative-versions-of-python-on-ubuntu-20-04-237be5177474) too.

Comment: After doing that, to check you are using the version you want, you can run `python --version`. The output should be `3.6` or `3.6.x`. Although, if you are updating why don't you get the latest `3.9.x` version instead?

Comment: You got it! :D It can be any folder you want although I would advise you not to use `/tmp` for it. For example: `python3 -m venv /home/<your username>/envs/<your_venv_name>`. Assuming `python3` or `python` are pointing to the right version.

Comment: Before installing any package, read the docs because you need to "activate" it first. Also, read about using a `requirements.txt` file to keep your project's dependencies updated and easily install them in another machine.

Comment: thanks ok I got it and it's activated, got my new python3.9 running too and my first django command worked, was able to start a project. But now I'm getting errors like:     
from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
so this makes me think my venv python isn't connecting to whatever it needs to, that is usually in my non-venv system right? also tried installing sqlite3 in my venv and can't get past this "No module sqlite3" error

Comment: Ok, aparently you're missing some packages. Is `sqlite` or `sqlite3` installed in your OS already?

Comment: I think you should create another post with your new problem, there is a better chance for you to get it solved soon. Don't forget to explain what you already have done (current setup, etc). Once you have it running, add a comment here to your new question in case someone is having a similar problem and consider marking this one as solved.

Answer (score 0):

(Not an Expert)

From what i see it could be an IndentationError or TabError, if your pulling the code from git or something don't change anything or add/remove any spaces using Nano/vim if your not familiar with them.

Comment: ok, this strange syntax error just pops up everytime I try to do anything with django-admin though. I don't really care about the syntax here or its not like I'm trying to run a .py thing or anything. I just want django to work,